# Solr MoreLikeThis for a single document

Tags: solr, lucene, e-commerce, morelikethis

I'm fairly new to Solr. I'm interested to implement MoreLikeThis feature of Solr for an e-commerce application. When a user clicks a particular product and goes into the Product Detail Page, I want the related products of that one product. I have to then filter out the results for different scenarios (similar color, types, brands, etc.)

I'm able to get the related products of result set by adding the mlt paramter as true in the Solr query.

My question is can a query be generated at runtime when a user enters the PDP page and can filters be applied for the MoreLikeThis result set?

P.S.: I'm in a Java environment

Comment: Both of these cases is supported by the MoreLikeThis query parser: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/morelikethis.html#morelikethis-query-parser if I understand your question right. I'm not sure what a "PDP page" is.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for the response. I looked into the link. But still I'm not sure if MoreLikeThis produces all combinations of the search query or only the most similar ones. For example, say the search query is "Black Nike shoes", will it return all black products and Nike products and shoes or only the most similar ones?

P.S.: PDP means the Product Details Page which you would go into after clicking the product link